# Prop types for children component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I want to something as simple as this

```
<View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor, bottom }]}>
    {this.props.children}
  </View>
```

Here, What should be the appropriate props type for children?

Where children can be react-native component consisting of scrollView, TextInput, Text etc

```
<MyComponent> 
 <View> 
  <Text> Could be text </Text>
</View>
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one i've always used for children is:

```
static propTypes = {
   children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
       PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),  //as you can render an array of elements
       PropTypes.element                   //for a single component/element
   ]).isRequired
}
```